# if else header not redirecting

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to create a redirection but for some reason it is not working and for the life of me I can't figure out why. The if command works well but not the else.
Any suggestions?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name  WHERE uid='";
$sql=$sql .  $xoopsUser->uid("s") . "'  ";

// Get a specific result from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


   if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    print "<div class='blockTitle'><strong>DOWNLOADS</strong></div><p><br><p>";
    echo "<div align='center'>You currently have no projects pending payment.<p>If you just completed a     transaction but missed the link on the PayPal page, click <a     href='http://site.co.uk/site/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=6'>here</a>.</div>";
}

  else{
 header('Location: http://site.co.uk/site/myComposerList2.php');
}
```

Comment: Put an `exit;` behind `header();`

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What's the error you get? Is there any code after the if-else block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `exit`, `header` wont stop the script from executing instantly.

Like this:

```
header('Location: http://site.co.uk/site/myComposerList2.php');
exit;
```

Comment: So what happens, when else clause is called? blank page, some error?

Comment: I got it: exit is what I needed but it wasn't working because the page was rapped into my cms site with this code:  include("mainfile.php");
include(XOOPS_ROOT_PATH."/header.php"); I've removed it and it works. Thanks JTC.

Comment: As on php.net, remember Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, it is very common  to use include with some echos or blank spaces